# Can't import cv2; "DLL load failed"

Tags: python, windows, opencv, numpy, windows-10

I really didn't want to start my own question with this because it seems to be a common error here. However, having wasted hours on this now and having followed every thread I could find, none of the given answers have sorted this for me.

So my only option is to provide all the information I can about my set up and hope one of you lot can recognise the problem.

I'm running on windows 10(x64) and have installed the following prebuilt binaries from the collection [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

1. python 3.5.0-win32 (installed from python website)
2. numpy 1.10-cp35-win32
3. matplotlib 1.4.3-cp35-win32
4. opencv 3.0.0-cp35-win32

Everything was installed using "pip install file_name.whl" with no error messages.
However the difference is open cv will not import and I get the following error:

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

**cv2.cp35-win32.pyd** plus many **.dll** files are installed to **C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages**

I've tried renaming **cv2.cp35-win32.pyd** to **cv2.pyd** and copying the **.dll** files to **C:\Python35\DLLs**

I've tried using another python opencv package downloaded from the site, adding the bin directory to my PATH environment and moving the **cv2.pyd** file to **C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages**

The same error appears every time. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It works on Python 3

Comment: pleas cheak you environment variables. did it include the right direction.
if not. [envs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41158148/6952434)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DLL load failed error when importing cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my situation, when using Pycharm to import cv2, it returned ***ImportError: DLL not found***. However, using python intepreter to import I got ***ImportError: ... not a win32 DLL ... *** instead. So, in this situation, I had to download Visual C++ 2015 redistribution package and problem solved.

So to anyone who meets the same error, please make sure you have the VC++ redistribution package which was used to compile the DLL packed along the module.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Importantly I had to unistall everything to do with Python including everything in the path variable before trying again from the beginning. This time I included the VC++ Redistributable and it seemed to work.

Comment: I wouldn't say this addresses the question posted. In my case I get the same error both in Pycharm as well as in the IDLE "The specified module could not be found"

Answer (score 8):

I had the error with Python 3.4 and opencv-python 3.3 on Windows 10. In my case the problem was due to my Anaconda distribution. I solved it with the solution from the opencv-python [project page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python), which points to this [github issue](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/36).

The problem is a missing `python3.dll` in the anaconda distribution. You can download the python binaries [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/) and extract dll out of the zip archive. Put it in a folder in your PATH (e.g. C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3) and the import should work.

Comment: +1 this worked for me, but after downloading the appropriate python3.dll version (not necessarily the 3.5.2 version pointed by the link in the answer). _E.g._ check `python -V` or `conda info` to find out the python version, and then find the appropriate release in this list: https://www.python.org/downloads/). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

(Running Python 3.6.3 - 32bit, on Windows 7 - 64bit)

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, opencv-python contains the main modules and opencv-contrib-python contains the main modules plus additional contrib modules, see https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ (do not try to install both of these!)

Comment: This worked for me on windows 10 running python 3.6.3 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

In my case (for Windows OS), issue is solved by

Adding opencv DLLs path to PATH environment variable.

You can follow [this](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) guide on how to add path to an environment variable

Comment: I solved the problem using this solution.
In my case, I have compiled the OpenCV library using visual studio.
Thanks

Comment: can you display how u add the path

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I've got it working by completely uninstalling everything and starting from the beginning with Python 2.7.10.

It simply just does not work with Python 3. For clarity on what I did I followed these two videos in the order I'm posting them:

[How to install opencv + dependencies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMXldo27L8c)

[How to set up the path variable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcFtefHEEII)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem with uninstalling all Visual C++ Redistributable Packages until 2008 and then installing Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for VS 2015. The explanation is here: 
http://answers.opencv.org/question/74384/opencv-python-30-with-python-35-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Windows 10 Professionnal N and solved it just by installing the Media Feature Pack (and restarting windows after installation).

> Windows N and KN editions do not include Media Feature Pack which is required by OpenCV. If you are using Windows N or KN edition, please install also [Windows Media Feature Pack](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3145500/media-feature-pack-list-for-windows-n-editions).

From https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python