# How to install opencv library in python 3.5?

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I've created a project in Pycharm IDE. I've used python 3.5, `tensorflow` library. Now I want to install `opencv` in this. 
I have tried so many videos available on youtube and some tutorials in the internet. But when import open cv in python shell it gives me following error. How can I fix it?
**import code**

```
import cv2
```

**Error message**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import cv2
>   ImportError: Module use of python27.dll conflicts with this version of Python.

I have noticed that **python 2.7 is used to install opencv**. Is it a must o use 2.7 version?
Also as I know **tensorflow will not support if I use another version of python(other than 3.5)**

Answer (score 3):

You can try using

```
python -m pip install opencv-python
```

This method uses the unofficial OpenCV PyPi wheels for Linux, Mac and Windows

Comment: Yes, I did this way.

Answer (score 1):

Did you download open cv for Python 3? Try this:

1. Make sure you have numpy installed
2. Download open cv for Python 3 from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv
   (not sure if this will work with Python 3.5, should work with 3.2)
3. Run `pip install opencv_python-your_verison_here.whl`

Comment: Where should I copy this download file?

Comment: I think that you should run pip in the directory where the whl file is located. If you downloaded .whl to c:\Users\George\Downloads, just open cmd, enter `cd c:\Users\George\Downloads` and than `pip your_commands`. Also, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file

Comment: Does these binaries really work. I mean opencv is a big library and can't be packaged into a single wheel

Comment: @Arthur, Thanks for the answer but didn't work. Still get the incompatible problem

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I can't help you more remotely. Maybe try to follow some tutorial? You could also uninstall/unregister Python 3 and install Python 2.7 only and than download and install OpenCV for Py2.

Comment: @Artur, well Tensorflow doesnt work for the python 2.7. That is a problem too. Do you know whether Scikit work in python 3.5? I could see it support upto 3.4

Comment: I guess it should work but I can't confirm, I haven't updated to 3.5 yet.

Answer (score 1):

Since PyCharm is tagged I'm assuming you are wanting to know how to get opencv installed in PyCharm specifically. There is a [PyCharm guide for installing packages here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html).

Step by step would be...

1. `File | Settings | Project:MyProject | Project Interpreter`
2. `Click the + symbol on the right`
3. `Type opencv-python`
4. `Select opencv-python`
5. `Click Install Package at the bottom left`

Opencv should now be added to PyCharm. You can verify that it is by...

1. `Tools | Python Console...`
2. `Clicking in the console window which pops up on the bottom`
3. `import cv2`

Comment: I tried this solution. But when I import the package it gives me an error.        
> Traceback (most recent call last):         
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>        
 File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import        
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)      
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: Found a [useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200025/cant-import-cv2-dll-load-failed). They are saying you need to download the visual c++ redistribution package which I guess [is here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Comment: I will try this. Thanks a lot for this answer

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of suggestions on how to solve this, but this was actually very easy to solve when using Anaconda. The problem is not the **Visual C++ 2015 redistribution**, but rather the python3.dll which is missing from
*C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3* as your second link suggests.

A lot of these sites suggests downloading it manually, but according to this thread ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues#1394 the most recent anaconda packages should all include the missing **python3.dll** file. So by updating python with conda, this was solved:

```
**conda update python**
```

Answer (score -1):

try typing this into your terminal :

pip install opencv_python.

This worked for me.I have Python 3.5.2.