# opencv import failed in windows container (on Windows Server 2016)

Tags: python, c++, opencv, docker, windows-container

I run the following container to test my opencv-python environment on Windows Server 2016.

`docker run -i --rm python:2.7-windowsservercore`

(the `python:2.7-windowsservercore` image is an official python image which is base on `microsoft/windowsservercore`)

and in the interacive console, I got the opencv-python installed by:

`pip install opencv-python`

after this finished, I test the opencv-python package by:

`python -c "import cv2"`

but I got the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

then I installed python-2.7.13 on the host(not inside container), input the same pip install commands, and test `python -c "import cv2"` again, it won't report any error. I wonder if there are some DLL files are missing in the container? What package or software should I install in the container to fix this error?

Comment: You need to try it inside Windows server core installation and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200025/cant-import-cv2-dll-load-failed) I would put my money on you not having the required MSVC runtime. Assuming it was compiled with Visual Studio 2015 the runtime can be downloaded from [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Comment: tks, I have considered `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015`(both x86 and x64), but after trying it still not work.
and btw, even on the host, latest opencv needn't `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015`, after pip installed it will work well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [in this place.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a95032d2-c469-494a-b3f9-521b1389a6c9/cant-use-opencvpython-package-in-windows-container-windows-server-2016-standard?forum=windowscontainers)

Copy the following files from your host into your container's \System32 folder:

- msacm32.dll
- avifil32.dll
- avicap32.dll
- msvfw32.dll