# ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I try to use code, where I use `scipy` and `sklearn`, but I get an error: `ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']`.
I download and install there from [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy), but nothing changed.
Why can I change that?

Comment: How did you install it? What does `import numpy` give you?

Comment: @NilsGudat nothing. I download `whl` and install that using pip, but this error hasn't disappear

Comment: Nothing meaning no error, i.e. you can do e.g. `numpy.random.rand()` and it returns a random number?

Comment: When I try `import numpy` in console, I get `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 Win32`

Comment: Check [other questions on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls), there seems to be an issure with the numpy version you installed.

Comment: @NilsGudat I saw this question and after install from there site error hasn't disappear

Comment: Did you see the others answers mentioned in the link posted by @NilsGudat the second answer seems to be your solution.

Comment: @shivsn I check that, I have 64-bit windows, 64 python and 64-bit packages

Comment: I think the error message you see when running `import numpy` is an important piece of information, and you should edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is caused by environment variable.If you step in, you may found the error is 'DLL cound not found'. please check if the direction is included. [my answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41158148/6952434)