# Missing required dependencies when testing with py.test

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pycharm, pytest

I have a python file which contains classes and functions and a

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

construct. I want to test a class which is defined in this file with py.test. For my first "hello world"-test, my test-file only imports the file to be tested.

Running py.test in PyCharm results however in

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/unittest/datageneration_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main.datageneration import *
  File "[...]/main/datageneration.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "[...]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

My file to be tested has the import statements

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import expit
import sys
import os
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import json
import uuid
```

My conda environment.yml is

```
channels:
- conda-forge
- defaults
dependencies:
- pandas=0.20.3
- numpy=1.13.1
- ggplot=0.11.5
- python=3.6.2
- pytest=3.2.1
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Hope it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973666/importerror-missing-required-dependencies-numpy

Comment: If you are running from a conda environment, you need to point your pycharm to use that environment.

Comment: @Anup: The link suggests I delete ".pyc" files, but I don't see any in my folders.

Comment: @BoboDarph: My PyCharm is pointing towards that environment - both the general setting is such and the setting for that specific test.

Comment: Can you try explicitly uninstalling and re-installing numpy and pandas  in your conda env? Just open it in an anaconda prompt and do pip uninstall pandas
pip uninstall numpy
pip install pandas
pip install numpy. Taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939561/8085234

Comment: @BoboDarph: I reinstalled the entire conda environment from scratch, but this did not help. I added the versions of the package I am using in the question. Maybe it is a version issue? (Welcome in Python dependency hell?)

Comment: Probably numpy version doesnt match what pandas needs. Or numpy is being a tease and not exposing itself properly. Taken from another unfortunate soul: https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/205#issuecomment-318129677. Fix there was adding numpy.core._methods instead of numpy  to the dependencies.

Comment: @BoboDarph: Until I started with py.test, pandas and numpy played nice together.

Comment: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2075

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what helped, but I reinstalled/updated numpy and pandas with `conda install ...`. I was still left with an error about having wrong file names. After trying out a lot of stuff I found out that - even though I was using pytest, not the library `unittest` - I could not name the folder in which all my test files are "unittest". Renaming it to "unittests" solved that. Now everything works.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to avoid using the same names as [standard library modules](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html), because modules depending on the stdlib will end up importing your module. If the module can't be renamed, the import issue can be avoided by moving the module underneath a package (a directory with \_\_init\_\_.py in it).